# Configuration error on my asp.net azure service using devexpress

Tags: asp.net, azure, devexpress, cloud

I'm trying to publish my cloud service (which includes web role with devexpress 13.1 controls and worker role) to azure cloud.
Everything works very good on my local computer and the publish process complete successfully but when i'm trying to view the website on the cloud I get the following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.Configuration ErrorDescription: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'DevExpress.Web.v13.1, Version=13.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 31: 
>   Line 32: 
>   Line 33: 
>   Line 34: 
>   Line 35: 
>   Source File: F:\sitesroot\0\web.config Line: 33
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'DevExpress.Web.v13.1, Version=13.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' could not be loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
>   To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
>   Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
>   To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18045

Does someone know how to fix it?

Thanks for any help,
Tom.

Comment: Have you used Remote Desktop to get onto the box and see if the file was packaged and up there?  Make sure that the "copy local" is set to true on your reference for it in your solution so that it goes up.

Comment: What does line 33 of your web.config file have on it?